# ftp: connect :Connection refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I have got an IP address from BandwagonHOST, and created a user with root privilege:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
shaw    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

installed vsftpd:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
sudo ufw status
Status:inactive
```

copied `/etc/vsftpd.conf`from `/etc/vsftpd.orig` and configued it like the following:

```
anonymous_enable=NO# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
check_shell=NO
local_umask=000
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
ftpd_banner=You made it!
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
listen=NO
seccomp_sandbox=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
listen_ipv4=YES
```

then I tried to test it and got this:

```
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/vsftpd.userlist
shaw

root@ubuntu:/# su - shaw
shaw@ubuntu:~$ ftp 172.93.34.44
ftp: connect: Connection refused
ftp>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

The following is edited content:

I did miss the command `service vsftpd start`, and after that , got another problem:

```
initctl: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket 
/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory 
vsftpd: unrecognized service.
```

And the command `sudo service status` gave me the information `vsftpd stop/waiting`

Thank u for helping me.

Comment: Are you sure the `vsftpd` daemon is running?

Comment: Thank u for that! I did miss the command `service vsftpd start`, and after that , got another problem:`initctl: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
vsftpd: unrecognized service`. And the command `sudo service status` gave me the information `vsftpd stop/waiting` . I got no idea how to fix it right after searching. Can you be so kind to give a little hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve my problem.That was reinstalling vsftpd,and directly ran the service instead of after configuring.And it turned out that the `/etc/vsftpd.conf`file was the point.So I just added what I needed and tested vsftpd service after every adding action.